# What deities did only one city/state recognize?

Tags: greek, roman, daemon

In research of past questions, I came across [Eleos](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleos). Eleos is the personified daemon (lesser/inferior god) of piety, mercy, clemency (leniency), and compassion. She was always depicted as a young woman wearing a blue veil or dress. She was only recognized as a deity in Athens. But if one wished to be allied with Athens, they were to approach Eleos's statue/altar as a suppliant.

Her Roman form was [Clementia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clementia). In 44 BCE, it's believed that Caesar had the Roman State erect a temple to her as he was keen to demonstrate his virtue. After that, not much is known.

Did other Greek/Roman cities/states have a deity they exclusively worshipped or recognized?

Answer (score 2):

In the period before Judaism became monotheistic, each city had its own deity. Remnants of this can be found in the Old Testament, for example:

- El Bet' el (Gen. 31:13; 35:7)
- El 'Olam (Gen. 21:33)
- El Ro'i (Gen. 16:13)
- El 'Elyon (Gen. 14:18)
- El Saddai (Gen. 17:1)

all later taken to be Yahweh after Moses, were all originally separate city gods worshipped by the early Hebrews.

This becomes especially clear if you look at the original text and not an English translations, as none of these translations correctly renders the original Hebrew of, for example, Genesis 31:13, which quite simply reads "I am the god Bethel" ('El Bet'el), who was a member of the Canaanite pantheon along with the rest of the above. The original meaning is therefore quite different from the traditional understanding: this god at Bethel (also a city name) is not the universal deity who appeared at Bethel but just one god among many – a local deity of a specific place.